# What is the groovy way for doing this initialization?

Tags: groovy, initialization

Hi what is the grrovy way of doing this kind of initialization?

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
   for(j=0; j<20; j++)
      for(k=0; k<20; k++)
         m[i][j][k]='a'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could do:

```
(0..9).each { i ->
    (0..19).each { j ->
        (0..19).each { k ->
            m[i][j][k] = 'a'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys. Both answers do the job.

Answer (score 4):

Based on *ccheneson* code:

```
10.times { i ->
    20.times { j ->
        20.times { k ->
            m[i][j][k] = 'a'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how efficient this is. Concise though.

```
final m = new char[10][20][20]
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
   for(j=0; j<20; j++)
      for(k=0; k<20; k++)
          m[i][j][k]='a'

final n = [[['a'] * 20] * 20] * 10 as char[][][]

assert n == m
```